# Javascript game trouble

Tags: javascript, arrays, html, canvas

I am making a game in Javascript with HTML5's canvas API and have hit a roadblock.

One of the games effects is a missile travelling upwards along the y axis, which is influenced by gusts of wind (emitted by turbines) which move it along the x-axis. I've had no problem with making one of these turbines, but when their number is increased to 3 I run into trouble. 
Upon a new level, I instantiate these turbines as objects, which are then pushed into an array, as can be seen here:

```
function gameStateNewLevel(){

    for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++){
        turbine = {};
        turbine.width = 10;
        turbine.height = Math.floor(Math.random()*200); //turbine height
        turbine.y = Math.floor(Math.random()*600) //turbine y-axis 
        if (Math.random()*10 > 5){ //indicates turbine side of canvas
            turbine.side = leftSide;
        }else{
            turbine.side = rightSide;
        }
        if(turbine.height <= 100){ //Increases turb. size if it's too small
            turbine.height += Math.floor(Math.random()*100);
        }

        turbines.push(turbine);

    }

    context.fillStyle = "#FFFFFF"       
    switchGameState(GAME_STATE_PLAYER_START);
}
```

Now, before they are rendered, they are also updated through an updateTurbine function. All this function should do is make sure that the turbines are not overlapping each other and move them up or down the y axis as necessary (by cycling through the array and comparing each of the objects in it). I've given a go at making the function, but I'm completely lost between all the loops. This is about as far as I've got, and I have a feeling I'm on the wrong track:

```
function updateTurbines(){
    tempTurbine = {}
    turbinePositionTop = tempTurbine.y;
    turbinePositionBottom = tempTurbine.y + tempTurbine.height;
    for (var i = turbineArrayLength; i < 2; i++){
        tempTurbine = turbines[i];
        for (var i = turbineArrayLength; i < 2; i++){
            if (tempTurbine !== tempTurbines[i]){
                while (){

                }
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

You can find source code and the furthest I got without this thing breaking at www.techgoldmine.com

Comment: Suggestion: your `if(turbine.height <= 100){` should be a `while(turbine.height <= 100){` in case the new number is still under 100.

Comment: @Jeffrey or just use `100 + Math.random()*100` from the start...

Comment: @Andrew yeah... that's probably a better idea :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are errors in your code, see the comments here:

```
function updateTurbines(){
    tempTurbine = {}
    turbinePositionTop = tempTurbine.y; // tempTurbine is an empty object right now so .y is undefined
    turbinePositionBottom = tempTurbine.y + tempTurbine.height; // same problem here
    for (var i = turbineArrayLength; i < 2; i++){ // why am I starting at the end of the array? What's the 2 for?
        tempTurbine = turbines[i];
        for (var i = turbineArrayLength; i < 2; i++){ // why am I doing this twice? I'm also clobbering the value of "i"
            if (tempTurbine !== tempTurbines[i]){
                while (){

                }
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

Here's how I'd rewrite that without knowing what its doing:

```
function updateTurbines(){
    var l = turbines[i].length; // get the turbine length directly from the array[1]
    for (var i = 0; i < l; i++){ // go through all of the turbines
        var tempTurbine = turbines[i];
        turbinePositionTop = tempTurbine.y; // now .y is defined because tempTurbine is not an empty object
        turbinePositionBottom = tempTurbine.y + tempTurbine.height;
        for (var j = 0; j < l; j++) { // NOT i but j here
            if (tempTurbine !== tempTurbines[j]){
                while (){
                     // ...
                }
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

[1] this might cause errors if you modify the array. I'm assuming you only ever add to it for now.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'll give this a shot tomorrow and tell you how it turns out, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Hey, just wanted to say that you were close but it was wrong. 

    var l = turbines[i].length;

This only got the length of the current object. tempTurbine was also not defined properly and on line 8 it should've been tempTurbine[j].
Either way it didn't work. I've posted the working code in the answers.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is likely that the indexes are overlapping; the inner loop is changing the `i` value for the outer loop.

I changed `i` to `j` in the inner loop.

```
function updateTurbines(){
    tempTurbine = {}
    turbinePositionTop = tempTurbine.y;
    turbinePositionBottom = tempTurbine.y + tempTurbine.height;
    for (var i = turbineArrayLength; i < 2; i++){
        tempTurbine = turbines[i];
        for (var j = turbineArrayLength; j < 2; j++){
            if (tempTurbine !== tempTurbines[j]){
                while (){
                    //What the heck is going on here?
                }
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

Let me know if that fixed it.

Comment: Thank you also, it wasn't a matter of fixing as much as just clarifying how the function needed to look. I'll also bear your advice in mind. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

The replies were helpful, but none of them worked... this is the code I got in the end.

```
function updateTurbines(){
    var l = turbines.length; 
    for (var i = 0; i < l; i++){ // go through all of the turbines
        var tempTurbine1 = turbines[i];
        tempTurbine1.PositionTop = tempTurbine1.y; // now .y is defined because tempTurbine is not an empty object
        tempTurbine1.PositionBottom = tempTurbine1.y + tempTurbine1.height;
        for (var j = 0; j < l; j++) { // NOT i but j here
            var tempTurbine2 = turbines[j];
            if (tempTurbine1 !== tempTurbine2 && tempTurbine1.PositionBottom >= tempTurbine2.PositionTop){

    }
   }
  }
 }
```